# Combinations with replacement of restricted selection of elements with repeats

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem:

The letters of the word RIGIDITY are written down on 8 cards, one on each card. 5 letters are selected, one at a time, with replacement after each selection. How many possible strings of letters can be chosen, bearing in mind that each letter may appear more than once?

In general, I am interested in understanding how, for a case of $n$ elements (containing $a_1$, $a_2$, ... repeats; here $a_1 = 3$ for R is the only repeated element) from which $k$ are selected, to calculate the number of combinations *with replacement*.

For combinations without replacement, I'd sum C(n,r) = C(5,5-j) from j=0 to j=3, for an answer of 26. Or in general, sum $C(n,k-(i+j+k...))$ from $i=0,j=0,k=0,...$ to $i=a_1,j=a_2,k=a_3,...$. What's the equivalent for combinations *with* replacement?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. Our set contains $6$ distinct letters, and we choose from that set $5$ times, so shouldn't your answer trivially be $6^5$?

Comment: Using the letters of the RIGIDITY with replacement is equivalent to selections from the set $\{R, I, G, D, T, Y\}$ with replacement.  Sohom Paul has answered that question.  A more interesting question would be "How many five-letter strings can be formed with the letters of the word RIGIDITY?", where it is understood that each letter could appear in the string as many times as it appears in the word RIGIDITY.